# Excel VBA - Changing formula values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a macro that can change the values in 3 cells, run solver subject to a changing constraint, and then paste the solved value in a column. repeat.

In cells L78,79 and 81 I have references to columns L, R and P respectively.

Here's basically what I'm doing each time I update the values:

```
L78 = **L4**,  
L79 = **R4**,  
L81 = **P4**,

Run Solver

Objective: $M$73
By changing variable: $L$80

Constraint: $M$73=**M4**

Solve

Copy $M$73

Paste **N4**
```

I would then increase all the values in ** by 1 row and repeat.

First time here so I apologize for any poor formatting.

Dan

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and seeing what it does?

Comment: I have and it works fine however I do not know how to make it update the row values everytime. As in it will just copy the same cells over and over.

Comment: Nice one, you have managed to do the job. Later on, you will be able to improve your code, e.g. through not using select or activate but rather by referencing directly.
A sidenote, without having seen your problem it might be possible to solve it using matrix algebra which is much more elegant. I did the VBA solver in my undergraduate thesis only to learn on the first day in my masters that all I needed was the correct maths (super simple once you are aware).

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to come up with some basic VBA that did the trick. Far from perfect as it uses copy and paste (lol) but it worked for my purpose, which was to run a binomial option pricing model and collect implied volatilities for a few hundred options.

Code is:

```
Sub Macro1()
Worksheets("Filtered Puts").Activate
RowCount = 3
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Filtered Puts").Range("H" & RowCount))
    Range("L" & RowCount).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L78").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("R" & RowCount).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L79").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("P" & RowCount).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L81").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("O73").Select
        SolverReset
    SolverOptions precision:=0.001
    SolverOk SetCell:="$M$117", _
        MaxMinVal:=1, _
        ValueOf:=0, _
        ByChange:="$L$80"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("M" & RowCount), _
        Relation:=2, _
        FormulaText:="$M$117"
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish keepFinal:=1
        Range("$L$80").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N" & RowCount).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```